# Fit the figure size after removing an axe - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I got a figure with 3 axes :
I did this :

```
fig.axes[1].remove()
```

So I removed the middle axe, but I would like that my left axis fill that is now empty (the white gap between the "map" plot and the colorbar see the image below)

How Can I do this ?
(Here is my whole code) :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
df_plot[df_plot['Risk_add_sin']==0].plot.scatter(x='x_rd', y='y_rd', c='Risk_add_sin', cmap=cmapm, ax=ax)
df_plot[df_plot['Risk_add_sin']!=0].plot.scatter(x='x_rd', y='y_rd', c='Risk_add_sin', cmap=cmapm, ax=ax) 
fig.axes[1].remove()
```

Thanks,
[image]

Comment: Someone just asked this yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the wrong question.

I believe you should pass `colorbar=False` to one of your `df.plot.scatter()` call to prevent the creation of one of the colorbar